# Default 'post' post type archive slug?

Tags: loop, templates, archives, post-type

I have a wordpress site, which has a front-page.php rendering a custom front page, so that this template will show no matter if WP admin settings is set to static page or show posts. The default setting is show posts in WP, so how can I get the 'post' post type archive slug, so my archive.php template can render a list of all posts no matter the WP setting?
----
With my custom post type 'event' - I can get the archive template from mysite.com/event (slug is set to 'event'). I want to do the same with the 'post' post type - so i can get target the archive template with for instance mysite.com/blog

Comment: I don't get what you mean - **archive.php** shows your selected archive, for example Posts from January 2015.  And the slug for the post type **Post** is `post`.  Perhaps you could clarify your question to help us (me) understand?

Comment: @DavidGard of course. Ive updated my question, which i hope clarifies it a little :)

Comment: If the slug is post, shouldnt mysite.com/post show my post archive template?

Comment: Please make sure you post all relevent info in your question so that we don't waste our time posting irrelevant info. Thank you

Comment: @PieterGoosen You are right. I thought there was a more straight forward answer for this that I didnt know about. My bad.

Comment: I don't believe that you can do this with Posts (at least not by default). For example, if you were to navigate to **http://www.yoursite.com/2014/12** you'd see all posts from December 2014, displayed using the **archive.php** template.  You can generate an archive list using [`wp_get_archives()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives), but basically the page you set as **posts page** in **Settings -> Reading** is  the equivilent of your all posts archive, similar to the example of **event** that you give in your question.

Comment: Thanks for a clarifying input David. I think I need to find a way to make the default page settings as a static front page and create a new site as the blog archive viewer..

Comment: hah, I need the same thing. Built-in Posts don't seem to have the same archive structure as custom post types?